# Visual Studio "Find All" not looking in all files

Tags: visual-studio

When using "Fin Add" (`Ctrl+Shift+F`) within Visual Studio 2015 update 3 to find all instances of a text, I noticed that `.csproj` (and may be other) have been ignored. If I open these files with any text editor, I can see what I'm looking for but find results in VS is empty.

Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: What did you specify in "Search In"?

Comment: @SLaks "Look in:" Entire Solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Entire Solution` only searches files that are parts of the projects in the solution.
The project files themselves are not parts of the projects.

Instead, you should specify a folder.